# My script is giving me an error on the length of a component

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixture-model

I have to represent with ggplot a mixture of 3 Poissons and superimpose the density of the components but it doesn't work. Every time ggplot is either empty or flat.

I tried this method and one where everything was separated.

```
# Rstudio
# Definisci i parametri delle tre distribuzioni di Poisson e i pesi
weights<- c(0.2, 0.08, 0.72)
lambda <- c(2.5, 30.4, 14.3)

# Crea un dataframe con i dati della mistura di Poisson
data <- tibble(x = 0:20, pdf_mixture = rowSums(sapply(1:3, function(i) weights[i] * dpois(0:20, lambda[i]))))

# Crea il grafico utilizzando ggplot2
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = pdf_mixture, color = factor(1:3))) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  labs(title = "Funzione di Densità della Mistura di 3 Poisson",
       x = "Valori",
       y = "Densità") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "purple"),
                     labels = c("Componente 1", "Componente 2", "Componente 3"))
```

This is the error:

```
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (21)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `colour`
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  3.   ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
  4.   └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5.     └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
  6.       ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
  7.       │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
  8.       │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  9.       │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 10.       │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 11.       │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 12.       └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13.         └─l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 14.           └─ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
 15.             └─ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)
```

Comment: Basically what the error says: your `color` aesthetics length is currently 3 while it should be either 1 (so it could be recycled) or match the length of your dataset, 21. A common approach would be having colour factor in your dataset. You could also use `color = rep(factor(1:3),7)`  . Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't believe you'd get the plot you are actually after with that kind of data arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

You could add color as a column to your data.frame

```
# ...

data$color <- factor(rep(1:3, 7))

# Crea il grafico utilizzando ggplot2
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = pdf_mixture, color = color)) +

# ...
```